# Android Studio - Git Repo - Push Commits Window - remove files from push

Tags: android, git, github

I am working with **Android Studio 1.5** in **Ubuntu 15**.

My problem is that I see a lot of files in the **Push Commits** window under `VCS -> Git -> Push...`, which I do not want to push into the repo.

---

*How can I remove the files from that window, so the click on push in the **Push Commits** window wont be pushing them?*

(Where do I need to click?)

---

EDIT:
I tried `VCS -> Git -> Revert`, but the window is empty.

Comment: Please look at this link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051504/how-do-i-remove-git-from-android-studio-project

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the commits you don't want to push. But push will send all the local commits to remote origin.