# How do I completely remove Git from an Android Studio project?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I'm developing my first project with Android Studio and can't quite get Git and GitHub configured properly. I'd like to completely remove my project from Git/Git from my project and start fresh. How can I do this? Also, there is no .git folder in my project folder, so where are my git files stored locally and how can I completely start over with Git and GitHub?

I've set VCS to 'None' in Settings -> Version Control, but I don't think this removes Git. The directory shows as "Unregistered roots". I was also wondering if it is normal to have several directories showing in this view? At times I've had  and some directory, and at the moment I have my project directory and as Unregistered root "app ( [my app directory] )"...

At one point I managed to push stuff onto GitHub, but only some of my project files. Others, which I added to the project after the initial commit, showed up as unversioned, I added them and tried to commit and push, but couldn't. Also, they went back to unversioned every time I built my project. This is why I'd like to completely start over

Answer (score 48, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't remove it using Android Studio (there isn't a button for removing Git from a project). (Upd.: [now incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60539200/6296561), but the rest of this answer is still correct and functional, because Git still works the way this answer relies on).

In addition, `.git` is a hidden folder, meaning it's, well, hidden. `ls` needs `-a` to show it, and most file explorers don't show the folder.

Git is also not dependent on Android Studio in any way. All of the Git history is stored in the `.git` folder, and is usable with or without Android Studio.

---

There are (at least) three options.

The first method to removing it is fairly simple. So when you go into your project root, simply append `/.git` to the path.

So if your project root is `D:/files/SomeProject`, append the Git folder so the actual path becomes `D:/files/SomeProject/.git` and delete all the files and folders in there.

Alternatively, you can also use command prompt to delete it (note that this assumes you cd into the root dir first):

Windows:

```
rd /s /q ".git"
```

Linux/Mac:

```
rm -rf .git
```

And there's of course the option to show hidden folders, but this shows them everywhere. At least for Windows (10), search for `folder` (alternatively in an applicable language if your computer doesn't use English) and select "Show hidden files and folders". Scroll down until you find `Hidden files and folders` and select `show`. Other operating systems have different ways, most of which are likely covered somewhere on the internet (possibly a different Stack Exchange as well).

---

No matter which way you do it, now you just do `git init` and you've restarted it. All previous history will be gone, and the active tree will be the one left, so make sure you're on the right branch. When you delete the `.git` folder, there's no way to recover the history without re-pulling from a remote, and this assumes you have/use one.

Note that if your project is already uploaded to GitHub, you have to use the force flag (`-f`) for the push. Otherwise it'll just reject the push. **Use the `-f` flag extremely carefully**; it will cause problems for anyone else working on the repo (though this is only really a concern if there are others), and it will overwrite the current version of the repo stored on GitHub, or in any other remote you push to, and this is usually unrecoverable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! Turns out the .git folders were there but hidden as you said. I thought I had hidden folders showing in explorer since there were other folders showing which started with a dot. How silly! As I kind of suspected, my problems may have been due to having several folders showing as VCS root directories, including my app folder. I had a .git folder in both project and app folder. I must have messed up somewhere. I removed both and removed the directories from VCS settings, enabled VCS again for Git, did VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Share on GitHub and voilà!

Answer (score 89):

From Android Studio Preferences,(My Android Studio version 3.6.1)
Select Version Control->Select git Path-> Click ' - ' (minus button)->OK

Windows: File > Settings > Version Control > Select Project > '-' (Minus Button) >Apply > Ok

**UPDATE:**

Currently google updated this settings.So if you want to delete GitHub connection from your project  Open android Studio Settings ->Version Control ->Github -> click ' - ' (minus button) -> Apply -> OK

[image]

Comment: Looks like this solution is for a Mac

Comment: Windows: File > Settings > Version Control > Select Project > '-' (Minus Button) >Apply > Ok

Comment: Ubuntu: File > Settings > Version Control > Select Project > '-' (Minus Button) > Apply > OK (Same as WIndows)

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: @xarzu which OS?

Comment: @LinsLouis it is Ubuntu .  I found a fix for it by going into the Project Structure and making sure all the Dependencies were updated.

Comment: @xarzu  My OS is MacOs. Currently google updated this setting.So if you want to delete GitHub connection from your project  Open android Studio Settings ->Version Control ->Github -> click ' - ' icon -> Apply -> OK

Answer (score 15):

What I have done to remove Android Studio project binding to GitHub is:

1. I removed project on https://github.com first (you do not have to remove your project from GitHub though. Treat it as optional step)
2. To remove GitHub binding to Android Studio project you need to go in Android Studio to File -> Settings -> Version Control. But DO NOT expand it, just mark it. Then, on the right hand side change, Git to None (red arrow on the picture below indicate this)
   [image]
3. Finally remove hidden directory .git from your Project directory, this one which is specified in the picture below (I actually blurred mine :-) ).

Follwoing this three steps I were able to completely re-create fresh project on Github with the same Android Project.

What I do not like in the first answer (and I am not allowed to send comments yet) is that actually removes Github account, but do not remove binding between project in Android Studio and Github.

**EDIT**
In newer version of Android Studio (i.e. Flamingo), in bullet (2) you need to go to:
Settings -> Version Control -> Directory Mappings

Comment: Thanks. I deleted and connected again with other project.

Answer (score 7):

Just an updated screenshot of the location of said '-' button in Android Studio 2022.1.1 on Windows.[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is the current way to do it (March 2023).

Answer (score 4):

just remove hidden folder ".git" from your project folder

Comment: android studio  still think there is a git repo exist

Comment: Side note: If the project was open when you deleted the .git folder, you need to restart android studio.

Answer (score 2):

for ***Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1*** version, you should go to: File->Settings->Version Control->Directory Mappings->"-"(Minus Sign in Top Left corner)->Apply->Ok
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all the files in '.git' folder for that,
Go to this path:
"D:\file\YourProjectName\android"
and in search bar search for '.git' and delete all the files there.